# Get HttpOnly cookies using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to log in to a site programmatically using .NET's HttpWebRequest POST method (code's written in C#). Originally I sent the request to the login page, saved the response cookies to a CookieContainer, and made a second HttpWebRequest with the login details (email="MyEmail"&pass="MyPassword") encoded and streamed to the request.

As I didn't manage to log in, I checked the cookies attached to the login request using Fiddler, and discovered that some cookies are flagged as HttpOnly. That Is, these cookies don't appear in any response headers of previous requests (needless to say they don't appear in the script as well (html or js)).

I've done a little research and imported the Wininet.dll library to my code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062925/c-sharp-get-httponly-cookie).
Here's my code:

```
class CookieReader
{
    static int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0X000020000;

    [DllImport("Wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string url, string cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, int flags, IntPtr pReserved);

    public static string GetHttpOnly(string url)
    {
        int size = 1024;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(size);
        if (InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, builder, ref size, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:
Firstly, the InternetGetCookiesEx method always returns false, for any URL. Since I'm new to C#, my first suspicion was that something is wrong with my code.

Secondly, I can't figure out a way to combine the HttpWebRequest POST with the InternetGetCookieEx method. This method only gets a url as an argument, without any login details, and I don't know how it makes the request (I suppose it does).

I hope I've been clear... Advice will be much (so very much) appreciated.