# Send HTTP Requests after browsing to a page as separate requests for Web Crawling (Angular site)

Tags: angular, vba, web-crawler, winhttprequest, imanage

My company has recently upgraded to new version of iManage (a file archive system) and it no longer has libraries exposed to VBA. Due to company policy, I can run VBA but can't create VSTO/.NET addins.

I'm trying to fix an addin tool that inventories all items within a folder/subfolders.

The solution I'm currently exploring is to navigate to the folder in the new web portal, and then inventory from there. I can probably do classic webcrawl and click through links in the browser but that's going to be slow and pretty ugly. As it's an Angular application, I think I should be able to fire REST requests and parse the responses without waiting for page loads.

I'm having an issue with InvalidToken coming back as failed.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidToken",
    "message": "X-Auth-Token is invalid or missing"
  }
}
```

The current solution is to create a WebBrowser object within a UserForm in Excel VBA. This userform navigates to our iManage portal. I can then navigate the site and click a button to launch the requests.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Debug.Print WebBrowser1.Busy
    
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set Doc = WebBrowser1.Document
    Debug.Print Doc.cookie

    Dim Request As New WinHttpRequest
    Request.Open "GET", Url:="https://imanage.xxxx.com/work/web/api/v2/customers/1/libraries/CLIENT-JOB/tabs/CLIENT-JOB!9975487/children?limit=500&offset=0&total=true", ASync:=False
    Request.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    Request.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
    Request.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8"
    Request.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
    Request.setRequestHeader "Host", Doc.Location.host
    Request.setRequestHeader "Referer", Doc.Location.href
    'Request.setRequestHeader "Cookie", WebBrowser1.Document.cookie
    Request.setRequestHeader "Set-Cookie", WebBrowser1.Document.cookie
    Request.setRequestHeader "X-XSRF-TOKEN", Split(Split(WebBrowser1.Document.cookie, ";")(2), "=")(1)
    Request.send

    Dim Result As String
    Result = Request.responseText
    Debug.Print Result
    
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     WebBrowser1.Navigate2 "https://imanage.XXXXX.com/work/web/r/custom2/recent-custom2?exclude_emails=true&scope=Admin,AdminArchive,Client-Job,JobArchive&p=1"
End Sub
```

Which I feel is replicating the request calls I can see in Chrome.
[image: Chrome Request Details]

I think a big part of the issue is the HTMLDocument I see within the WebBrowser never lists all of the same cookies that I can see in Chrome.

[image: Object in VBA]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies flagged as "HttpOnly" in that last screenshot are not retrievable using `document.cookie`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript
> Document.cookie API; it is sent only to the server. For example,
> cookies that persist server-side sessions don't need to be available
> to JavaScript, and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution
> helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Maybe you can try: [Retrieve ALL cookies from Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726408/retrieve-all-cookies-from-internet-explorer)

Comment: eagle eyes there!